# Error on boot, Dependency failed for boot

Tags: boot, failure

[image]

Hello, suddenly an error occur during booting. Any idea?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: WRT "suddenly", is this an operating system install you have been using for a while, or a new card?

Comment: yes, i have been using Raspbian for 1 year installed in sd card

Comment: Possibly the file system is corrupted in a way it cannot be repaired.  The only possibility for you to do much about that depends on whether you can try to mount and access both partitions on the card, which generally means you need another linux system.  This could be the Pi itself if you have another SD card you can put a new system on and run it with that, then use a USB adapter with the damaged card, or a virtual machine inside a window or mac computer.

Comment: Thank you! Is there any way to clone the existing data to another sd card?

Comment: You can duplicate any card regardless of what's on it (I'd use `dd`; presumably there are other ways depending on the OS you are using), but the duplicate will have the same problems as the original so there is not much use in that unless the card itself is physically defunct/worn out.

Comment: To clone the data from a possibly corrupt SD card is a bad idea.